# Antenna and balun for MRF49XA

Tags: rf, antenna, balun

I am trying to do a project that involves proximity detection. I need a few devices omnidirectionally detecting each other at short distance (under 20 feet). It seemed to me that sub-1Ghz RF is the way to go. I got a few [MRF49XA](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/70590c.pdf) transceivers. The datasheet for the chip provides a reference balun circuit schematic, but considering my requirements, I wonder if I really need one and if I do, can I get a pre-made balun IC rather than building my own. All I need is for the devices to be able to detect each other at around 15-20 feet range, hopefully with the lowest possible analog RSSI value and get to highest RSSI when right next to each other.

I do not have EE education and I am very new to the field, so if the question doesn't make sense or requires more information, please be patient with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read quickly the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70590C.pdf) (page 73), you'll see that you have to use a balun circuit in order to match the IC's pins high input impedances to the antenna's impedance which is likely to be [50 \$\Omega\$](http://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/why-fifty-ohms)

If you go further and read page 13 :

> The LNA has approximately 250 \$\Omega\$ of differential input
>   impedance which functions well with the proposed antenna 
>   (PCB/Monopole)  during  signal transmission. The LNA, when connected
>   to the 50 \$\Omega\$ device, needs an external matching circuit
>   (Balun) for correct matching and to minimize the noise figure of the
>   receiver.

So you definitely need a 50 \$\Omega\$ unbalanced to 250 \$\Omega\$ differential impedance matching circuit, the technology you want to use is up to you.

In RF electronics, [impedance matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching) between interconnected circuits is mandatory, should it be for signal integrity reasons or hardware safety reasons.

Comment: Hmm... so, do I have to make the exact circuit in the datasheet or can I use something like this maybe?
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/249/TP-103-477720.pdf

Comment: See edit. You can for example use something LIKE the TP-103 but not the TP-103 because it outputs 200 ohm diff. instead of 250 diff.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies things. I am too noob to figure out what numbers to look for :)

Comment: A possibly stupid question. What if I don't plan to use an antenna? What is the impedance of "no antenna" or "strip of metal on PCB"?

Comment: Approximately infinity at your frequencies (it's a small strip line terminated by an open circuit) which would cause no damage since you are doing reception, but you'd not receive anything though